# Regex pattern to match "AA BB CC DD"

Tags: regex

I have a hexadecimal string with `space` separator for each byte.

eg., `A1 B2 C3 D4 E5 FF 00 11 22 33 44 ...`

I would like to use a regex validator to verify the user input is correct or not?

How could I write the regular expression to achieve this goal?

Comment: `^[A-F0-9]{2}( [A-F0-9]{2})*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
 ^[A-F0-9]{2}( [A-F0-9]{2})*$
```

Explanation:

```
 ^               - anchor: string start 
 [A-F0-9]{2}     - two symbols in either 0..9 or A..F range
 ( [A-F0-9]{2})* - followed by space and two 0..9 or A..F symbols zero or more times
 $               - anchor: string end
```

If you allow `a..f` as valid hexadecimal symbols

```
 ^[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}( [A-Fa-f0-9]{2})*$
```

Comment: Thanks for you detail explanation.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a solution based on *DRY* principle
(Don't Repeat Yourself).

Instead of writing the same pattern (as *Dmitry* proposed), you can:

- Write the pattern for 2 hex digits as a capturing group - `([A-F0-9]{2})`.
- "Call" it again using `(?1)`.

So the whole pattern can be `^([A-F0-9]{2})( (?1))*$`.

There are also other variants of "calling" a capturing group, e.g.

- `(?-1)` - call the preceding group or
- `(?&name)` - call a named group.

For details see https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html

Comment: Thanks for your proposal... however, subroutine call seems not  supported in python and javascript? I think Dmitry's answer is more generic...